# Fetch record in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get the record on the basis of some field in ROR by this method

```
@indivisuals = Profile.find_by_manager_id(current_user.account.id)
```

but when i try to iterate it , it show me some error.

```
undefined method each' for undefined method each' for #<Profile:0x8383680>
```

related code:

```
<% if @indivisuals %>
  <% @indivisuals.each do |profile| %>
  <li><a href="accounts/show/<%=h profile.account_id %>" style="padding-left:10px;"><%=h profile.full_name %></a>&nbsp;<a href="accounts/edit/<%=h profile.account_id %>" style="padding-left:10px;">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" style="padding-left:10px;">Delete</a></li>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong .

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are getting a concrete object and not a relation to iterate with. You would instead need to change your finder like :

```
@indivisuals = Profile.where(:manager_id => current_user.account.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `find_all_by_manager_id` instead of `find_by_manager_id`

```
@indivisuals = Profile.find_all_by_manager_id(current_user.account.id)
```